# Failed to log into Google using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can't figure out why Google won't let me log into my account. I put my email inside a variable called `my_mail` then search for it in the html but the results came back false.

I am using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) & [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) modules to do so.

What I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

form_data={'Email': 'ExampleEmail@gmail.com', 'Passwd': 'Password'}
post = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password"
my_mail = 'ExampleEmail@gmail.com'

with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?elo=1").text, "html.parser")
    for inp in soup.select("#gaia_loginform input[name]"):
        if inp["name"] not in form_data:
            form_data[inp["name"]] = inp["value"]
    s.post(post, form_data)

print(my_mail in "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox")
```

Form info:

```
<form novalidate="" method="post" action="https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password" id="gaia_loginform">
  <input name="Page" type="hidden" value="PasswordSeparationSignIn">
  <input type="hidden" name="GALX" value="c90FYb-yd6E">
  <input type="hidden" name="gxf" value="AFoagUVMILWKQvqlGV0i8sJG83jiQlrWzg:1475424777331">
  <input id="profile-information" name="ProfileInformation" type="hidden" value="">
  <input type="hidden" id="_utf8" name="_utf8" value="☃">
  <input type="hidden" name="bgresponse" id="bgresponse" value="js_disabled">
  <input type="hidden" id="pstMsg" name="pstMsg" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" id="dnConn" name="dnConn" value="">
  <input type="hidden" id="checkConnection" name="checkConnection" value="youtube:230:1">
  <input type="hidden" id="checkedDomains" name="checkedDomains" value="youtube">
  <div class="form-panel first valid" id="gaia_firstform">
  <div class="slide-out ">
  <div class="input-wrapper focused">
  <div id="identifier-shown">
  <div>
  <label class="hidden-label" for="Email">
  Enter your email</label>
  <input id="Email" type="email" value="" spellcheck="false" name="Email" placeholder="Enter your email" autofocus="">
  <input id="Passwd-hidden" type="password" spellcheck="false" class="hidden">
  </div>
  </div>
  <span role="alert" class="error-msg" id="errormsg_0_Email"></span>
  </div>
<div style="display: none" id="identifier-captcha">
<input type="hidden" name="identifiertoken" id="identifier-token" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="identifiertoken_audio" id="identifier-token-audio">
<div class="audio-box">
  <div id="playIdentifierAudio"></div>
</div>
<div id="captcha-box" class="captcha-box">
  <div id="captcha-img" class="captcha-img" data-alt-text="Visual verification">
  </div>
  <span class="captcha-msg">
  Letters are not case-sensitive
  </span>
</div>
<label for="identifier-captcha-input" class="hidden-label"></label>
<input type="text" id="identifier-captcha-input" name="identifier-captcha-input" class="captcha" placeholder="Enter the letters above" title="Type the characters you see or numbers you hear">
</div>
<input id="next" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" type="submit" value="Next">
  <a class="need-help" href="https://accounts.google.com/signin/usernamerecovery?hl=en">
  Find my account
  </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin" tabindex="-1">
  <img id="back-arrow" class="back-arrow " aria-label="Back" tabindex="0" alt="Back" src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/arrow_back_grey600_24dp.png">
  </a>
  <div class="form-panel second">
  <div class="slide-in hide-form">
  <div>
  <p id="profile-name"></p>
  <span id="email-display"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
  <div id="password-shown"></div>
  </div>
<input id="signIn" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" type="submit" value="Sign in">
  <label class="remember">
  <input id="PersistentCookie" name="PersistentCookie" type="checkbox" value="yes" checked="checked">
  <span>
  Stay signed in
  </span>
  <div class="bubble-wrap" role="tooltip">
  <div class="bubble-pointer"></div>
  <div class="bubble">
  For your convenience, keep this checked. On shared devices, additional precautions are recommended.
  <a href="https://support.google.com/accounts/?p=securesignin&amp;hl=en" target="_blank">Learn more</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" name="rmShown" value="1">
  <a id="link-forgot-passwd" class="need-help" href="https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery?hl=en">
  Forgot password?
  </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <span id="inge" style="display: none" role="alert" class="error-msg">
  Sorry, Google doesn't recognize that email. <a href="https://accounts.google.com/SignUpWithoutGmail?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount">Create an account</a> using that address?
  </span>
  <span id="timeoutError" style="display: none" role="alert" class="error-msg">
  Something went wrong. Check your connection and try again.
  </span>
  </form>
```

I don't plan on using Google's API. I don't want to be restricted.

Why is the login failing? What could I do to fix it?

I need to login to scrap some information that requires a login.

Pyhton 3.4.2

Comment: `my_mail in "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"` is asking if the value of `my_mail` is contained in that **URL**, not the webpage that the URL points to. You'd need to actually scrape that page if you want to find something in it.

Comment: mind showing me an example? I tired `page = requests.get(https://accounts.google.com/)
print (page.text.encode('utf8'))` but it didn't show me proof I was logged in

Comment: Could you Help me? I've been searching all day for a solution

Comment: Try using `mail_text = s.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox').text)` to use your session to connect to the inbox page (do this inside the `with` block).